# Is it possible to use cypress and IIS Express on GitHub Actions?

Tags: asp.net, cypress, github-actions

I been trying to set up a cypress job on GitHub Actions with an ASP.NET app on the .NET Framework (4.5.1) web application using a Windows machine.

```yaml
  - name: Cypress run
    uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
    with:
      build: msbuild cypressdemo.web\cypressdemo.web.csproj -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile -p:DeployOnBuild=true
      start-windows: iisexpress /path:${{ github.workspace }}\cypressdemo.web\bin\app.publish /port:8080
      browser: edge
      headed: true
      wait-on: 'http://localhost:8080'
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Response sent: http://localhost:8080/ with HTTP status 500.0

If I run the command on the testing env I can get an IIS Express running with an HTTP status 200, I don't know if it's possible this way to test my app.

Comment: Receiving 500 actually indicates that IIS Express at least loaded your web app. To learn why an internal error occurred, you might enable FRT and read its logs (and make the logs something you can download in your GitHub Actions manifest). You can also set up a self hosting agent machine locally to see if you can reproduce the same error.